# Can HdfsSink3Connector create duplicates?

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

As per the [Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs3-sink/current/index.html), Sink Connector ensures Exactly-Once-Delivery.

How does it ensure Exact-Once-Delivery in case of connector task thread failure?

Does it remove the file created by the failed task thread? Or it leaves the corrupted/partial file in HDFS?

> The connector uses a write-ahead log to ensure each record is written to HDFS exactly once. Also, the connector manages offsets by encoding the Kafka offset information into the HDFS file so that it can start from the last committed offsets in case of failures and task restarts.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

The HDFS Connector is saving the offsets in the filenames and returning them to the consumer api in the connector in order to know from where it needs to continue, in this way it provides Exactly Once Semantics, EOS, and avoid duplicates.

> /**
>
> - HDFS Connector tracks offsets in filenames in HDFS (for Exactly Once Semantics) as the last
> - record's offset that was written to the last file in HDFS.
> - This method returns the next offset after the last one in HDFS, useful for some APIs
> - (like Kafka Consumer offset tracking).
> - 
> - @return Next offset after the last offset written to HDFS, or -1 if no file has been committed
> - ```
>   yet
>   ```
>
> */

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/blob/1d68023c38e17f0ed6f87f3b78d86c2e08f39909/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/hdfs/TopicPartitionWriter.java

The `offset` is being read from the file name

```
long lastCommittedOffsetToHdfs = FileUtils.extractOffset(
      fileStatusWithMaxOffset.getPath().getName());
  log.trace("Last committed offset based on filenames: {}", lastCommittedOffsetToHdfs);
  // `offset` represents the next offset to read after the most recent commit
  offset = lastCommittedOffsetToHdfs + 1;
  log.trace("Next offset to read: {}", offset);
```

If the hdfs file been written to disk, than on task start , the offset will be read from the filename and continue from that point...

If the file did not write to disk yet , on task it will start read again from before and try to write the file to hdfs, on success it will commit the offsets, if the commit fails but the file exists on hdfs, it will take the offset to continue from the hdfs file on task start –

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. Before committing the offset, if the task thread dies what would happen to the file being written

Comment: If the hdfs file been written to disk, than on task start , the offset will be read from the filename and continue from that point...

Comment: If the file did not write to disk yet , on task it will start read again from before and try to write the file to hdfs, on success it will commit the offsets, if the commit fails but the file exists on hdfs, it will take the offset to continue from the hdfs file on task start